# javascript call not working

Tags: javascript, html

This my code for trialindex.php. The code contains an html form which is submitted properly. I am trying to create a javascript function to be called when the form is going to be submitted. Right now there is only an alert in this function. But it the function isn't called when the form is submitted.

```
<?php session_start();?>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function try(){

    alert("Hello");

    }

</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="change">

    <form id="trialForm" method="post" action="connection.php" onSubmit="try()">

    <center>

    <h3><b>Login</b></h3>
    <br/>

    <label>Username :</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Password :</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Login"/>     

    </center>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript function try() doesn't seem to work. I have also tried several other calls for try like : try(); , javascript:try() , javascript:try();

But in any of the syntax no alert is popped. Also in my browser pop-up are not blocked.
Could you please suggest what could the possible problem be?

Comment: I think `try` is a reserved word.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch Yup, it's reserved.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: thank you @putvande... I changed the name and its done...  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `try` as a function name.
It is a reserved word:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Just use a different name for your function.

```
function my_submit_function(){

    alert("Hello");

}
```

It is good practice to check your console for errors.

Answer (score 1):

The error message I see is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token try

Which makes clear that `try` is not a method, but a `token` (or keyword).

If you rename `try` it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/c4zz3/).